Python.NET: Py.GIL thread taking super long to load in an ASP.NET Core Razor page
As title states - the OnGet output statement appears but "Reached line here" takes a super long time to appear in one of the Razor pages:
Index.cs.html.cs:
public void OnGet() {
    Console.WriteLine("On get");
    using (Py.GIL()) {
        Console.WriteLine("Reached line here");
    }
}

For context, I got the Razor page from a template via command
dotnet new webapp

I init PythonEngine globally in the main (Program.cs) file before running the app:
PythonEngine.Initialize();

Py.GIL thread seems to run instantly when I use it within the same file, or any .cs file that is not a .cshtml.cs razor page.
For example, the thread loaded instantly in the Resources.cs file if I do this in Program.cs:
using Python.Runtime;

class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Runtime.PythonDLL = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3";
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        Resources.initResources();
        // ...
    }
}   

Resources.cs:
static class Resources 
{
    public static void initResources() 
    {
        using (Py.GIL()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reached line here"); // printed instantly
            // ...
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Thread ends here"); // printed and thread ended successfully

        // ...
    }
}

But the Py.GIL thread doesn't load when I try to use it in the Razor page. The only way I can get this to work is if I shutdown PythonEngine, then reinit PythonEngine again each time I use the Py.GIL() thread.
This is the shutdown code:
PythonEngine.Shutdown();


Hi @Kyle Zheng, I saw you delete your answer. Did you work fine now? If so, I suggest you post the answer with detailed code instead of only the link.

They deleted it not me. Not my problem

Hi @Kyle Zheng, So I suggest you can post your answer with detailed code instead of only share the link, which would be helpful for other community members.

Solution:
PythonEngine.Initialize();
var m_threadState = PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
